# Need help identifying SMD IC

Tags: mosfet, voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

I have a Network Video Recorder, Chinese one, NBD8016S-XC v2.03. I think it had an electrical shock after power outage, just want to try to repair it. I have found the IC that is burnt, but can not find the replacement by its code. I will attach a picture if someone can have a look and recognize it I will be very grateful. I think on the package TPHaUA is written but nothing appears on google search:( [image] This one is the same component but next to the one that is burnt.[image]

Comment: Looks like SOT-23-6, but please check the dimensions of the capsule with a caliper. That could narrow down your search.

Comment: thanks, i was thinking the same, will try to measure and post the dimensions later tomorrow, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Function and pinout matches TPS560430Y, but there may be others with this pinout. The inductor 2.2 µH is a bit small for this circuit, but OK if used with <= 12 V input.

Comment: Thank you very much, looks like the winner, i will measure some voltages tomorrow on the working one and post back the results, thanks again for your help :)

Comment: TI got several generations and variants of these "simple switchers", pin compatible but different voltages, frequencies and inductors. Digging into TI datasheets for markings is a good idea.